# How to open first accordion in angular ui bootstrap with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there any option to open first accordion on the basis of **ngRepeat** ?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    oneAtATime: true
  };
  $scope.cards = [{
    "id": 1,
    "bankid": 999999,
    "type": "VISA",
    "no": "1234 5678 9012 3456",
    "from": "01/06",
    "expiry": "05/18",
    "cvv": 345,
    "name": "Kallayi Basheer Shah"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "bankid": 888888,
    "type": "Master",
    "no": "3456 7890 1234 5678",
    "from": "06/12",
    "expiry": "07/16",
    "cvv": 678,
    "name": "Shah Basheer"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "bankid": 777777,
    "type": "VISA",
    "no": "9012 3456 1234 5678",
    "from": "03/10",
    "expiry": "08/17",
    "cvv": 123,
    "name": "Basheer Shah Kallayi"
  }];
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <accordion close-others="status.oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="card in cards">
          <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> {{card.no}}</accordion-heading>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Name on card: {{card.name}}
              <br>Card type: {{card.type}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </accordion-group>
      </accordion>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js'></script>
```

Comment: Couldn't spot obvious mistake in the code, can you post a fiddle? Any console error message?

Comment: @Icycool Thank you for your attention on the question, here is the demo of the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwrVrB

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While assigning is-open to a model certainly works, if you are not planning to change the behavior dynamically, you can also fix it to the first element using

```
is-open="$first"
```

Comment: Perfect! haven't thought of this

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the angular-ui accordion has the `is-open` attribute which is compatible with `ng-repeat`.

Using `$first` works if all you have in your `<accordion-heading>` is static behavior/ content as @Icycool states in their answer.

If you wanted to make use of the changing chevrons angular-ui uses in their [accordion example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) however, this would not work.

In order to have the first item default to open and still maintain chevron (or other content) updates, simply give the first item its own accordion group, a boolean in the scope, and refer to the 0th index like so:

**accordionController.js:**

`$scope.isFirstOpen = true;`

**accordionExample.html:**

```
<accordion-group is-open="isFirstOpen" ng-if="cards.length > 0">
    <accordion-heading>
        <div>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i>
            <strong>{{cards[0].no}}</strong>
            <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': 
                         isFirstOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isFirstOpen}"></i>
        </div>
    </accordion-heading>
    <div>
        Name on Card: {{cards[0].name}} <br>
        Card Type: {{cards[0].type}}
    </div>
</accordion-group>
```

Then, create the rest similarly, giving them their own open boolean and using the array's `slice()` method to refer to all the rest of the items like so:

**accordionController.js:**

`$scope.isOpen = false;`

**accordionExample.html:**

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="card in cards.slice(1)" is-open="isOpen">
    <accordion-heading>
        <div>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i>
            <strong>{{card.no}}</strong>
            <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': 
                                   isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isOpen}"></i>
        </div>
    </accordion-heading>
    <div>
        Name on Card: {{card.name}} <br>
        Card Type: {{card.type}}
    </div>
</accordion-group>
```

---

Check out this **CodePen demo** to see it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdpNgB?editors=101

Comment: Much appreciated for your effort to find answer. You description in answer gives lot of knowledges. However I have already got single line solution as answer which doesn't require much time and coding lines.

Answer (score 0):

In the template, bind the is-open property of the accordion as follow:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="card in cards" is-open="status.isItemOpen[$index]">
```

and in the controller:  `$scope.status = { isItemOpen: [true] };`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    oneAtATime: true,
    isItemOpen: [true]
  };

  $scope.cards = [{
    "id": 1,
    "bankid": 999999,
    "type": "VISA",
    "no": "1234 5678 9012 3456",
    "from": "01/06",
    "expiry": "05/18",
    "cvv": 345,
    "name": "Kallayi Basheer Shah"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "bankid": 888888,
    "type": "Master",
    "no": "3456 7890 1234 5678",
    "from": "06/12",
    "expiry": "07/16",
    "cvv": 678,
    "name": "Shah Basheer"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "bankid": 777777,
    "type": "VISA",
    "no": "9012 3456 1234 5678",
    "from": "03/10",
    "expiry": "08/17",
    "cvv": 123,
    "name": "Basheer Shah Kallayi"
  }];
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <accordion close-others="status.oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="card in cards" is-open="status.isItemOpen[$index]">
          <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> {{card.no}}</accordion-heading>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Name on card: {{card.name}}
              <br>Card type: {{card.type}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </accordion-group>
      </accordion>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js'></script>
```

Comment: Why is this different than my answer?

Comment: @RazvanBalosinI I have just explained in the beginning of the answer, and also you can run the result when you click on  **Run code snippet**